# My tokens seem to be skipping over the leading whitespace of a text file

Tags: java, whitespace, token

Here is my output: "Four score and seven years ago...."

However, the expected input is: "      Four score and seven years ago..." (with a space between the quotation mark and 'four'".

How do I keep the leading whitespace? Here is my code so far.

```
public void checkDocument(Reader in, InputStream input, Writer out) throws IOException {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
TokenScanner tok=new TokenScanner(in);
Token too;
Set<String> fileCor=new HashSet<String>();
while (tok.hasNext()){
    too=tok.next();
    System.out.println(too);
    if (too.isWord()){
        if (!(dict.isWord(too.toString()))){
            int n=1;
            fileCor=corr.getCorrections(too.toString());
            List<String> sortedOptions=new LinkedList<String>(fileCor);
            Collections.sort(sortedOptions);
            System.out.println("The word: "+too.toString()+" is not in the dictionary. Please enter the number corresponding with the appropriate action:");
            System.out.println("0: Ignore and continue");
            System.out.println("1: Replace with another word");
            for (int i=0;i<sortedOptions.size();i++){
                n=n+i+1;
                System.out.println((i+2)+": Replace with \""+sortedOptions.get(i)+"\"");
                }
            int choice=getNextInt(0, n, sc);
            if (choice==0){

            }
            else if (choice==1){
                out.write(getNextString(sc).trim());
            }
            else out.write(sortedOptions.get(choice-2).trim());

        }
        else out.write(too.toString().trim());

    }
    else {
        out.write(too.toString());
    }

}
System.out.println("Document completed");

 }
}
```

Comment: [Trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted. May be that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.

So, if you need only trailing spaces to be removed use the below regex expression.

```
String newstr = str.replaceAll("\\s*$","");
```